# GCM priority message to device group

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM messaging to send a message to a device group without a server. Is there anyway to send an high priority message? I'm using this code:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
gcm.send(to, id, data);﻿
```

Comment: I asked Google yesterday. You should be able to set priority on downstream messages, even for device group messages. Please refer to the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message. Keep in mind that you should really only set the message priority to high only if the message is time-critical and requires the user’s immediate interaction, otherwise it may impede use experience and consume device battery more than normal.

Comment: I can't. I'm using device group without server.

Comment: Did you tried the Google code example for Android on GitHub: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There isn't any send() method that accept the priority.

Comment: If you are referring to sending messages to a device group, without a server, as per noted in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#sending-upstream-messages-to-device-groups, please note that this is for upstream messages. The priority parameter is only available for downstream messages.

Comment: @Suriyaa Kudo Yes, I know but this is a corner case because the message is forwarded directly from Google that transform upstream to downstream. Without a server it's impossible to set a priority in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you provided, It seems that you are sending an upstream message to a device group which means that you cannot set the priority level.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) states that it is currently applicable to [downstream messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications).

Comment: It's actually a downstream message because I'm using device group without server, but I think it's a corner case and maybe it's not possible.